# How can I make a button load on to the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button, html

to those who are reading this, would just appreciate already for you trying to help me.

Anyway, I am a beginner on coding. My problem is that I have a few set of buttons, it's actually for a theme layout I'm trying to achieve as a young newbie but I can't seem to figure out how to make those buttons getting clicked and load on just 1 specific box in a page. Others say it can be done by Ajax or JQuery or Javascript, but I have no idea, I only know HTML / CSS and that's just it really... I don't even know what this term i want to happen is called.

Could anyone possibly give me the easiest solution or example for me to follow?

I did try my best to do it by my own and researching, but I guess my skills weren't quite talented yet to fix the situation. Even tried asking my genius brother for help but so far he never makes anything easy for me or lend me a hand even when I am just trying to learn. He's just busy, as what he always says.

This is what I have tried doing so far: http://animiao.com/IMVU%20Coding/sample3.php
Perse, there is suppose to be a box on default showing up (like example the home page) and the rest of those 3 buttons are suppose to show their own information.

Problems:
They only show up in order when i click Chat > Message > Add button, not on any other order.
When I click them again, they don't show up.

Guess my methods are just way wrong, please do help.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on that. http://www.queness.com/post/328/a-simple-ajax-driven-website-with-jqueryphp Since this doesn't explain every single step, you might want to google "jquery ajax website tutorial" ( maybe additionally add php in there as well... ). You might want to learn the basics of jquery before tackling this though.. (  otherwise you might end up just copy pasting everything and not learn anything in the process.. )

Comment: Related but not required: No need to [re-invent the wheel](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) (however there is a lot to learn if you do it yourself rather than drag-and-drop a solution so if that's your intent, kudos.)

Comment: See this answer I did earlier today (not PHP, but Javascript) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858681/removing-elements-and-bringing-them-back-via-click/12858798#12858798

Answer (score 0):

All the `<div>`s are stacked on top of each other, and none have `z-index` specified with CSS. As a result, the one that appears on top will be the one that is
a) last in the HTML code
and b) visible

The simplest way to fix it is to wrap your content divs in another div:

```
<div id="content_wrapper">
    <div id="random">something...</div>
    <div id="chat">something...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

And then hide the ones you don't want with this JS:

```
var contents = document.getElementById('content_wrapper').childNodes,
    i = 0,
    i_max = contents.length;
for (i; i < i_max; i++) {
    contents[i].style.display = 'none';
 }
```

And follow *that* with your "show" code:

```
var el = document.getElementById(id);
if (el.style.display == 'none')
    el.style.display = 'block';
```

This can be condensed down to less code with ease, but will also make it less obvious for you to understand, so I'll leave it as this for now.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldnot harm if you learn a bit of javascript
Simple example for javascript

save these two line as ajax_sample.txt

```
<p>AJAX is not a new programming language.</p>

<p>AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages.</p>
```

now create one file like say a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

try to load  a.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you display an element you aren´t hiding the others:
if you do for example

```
var el = document.getElementById(id);//id = chat
if (el.style.display == 'none')
```

you also need hide the others elements:

```
 var message = document.getElementById('message');
 var add = document.getElementById('add');
 message.style.display == 'none';
 add .style.display == 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

html part:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Button1"></input>
<input type="button" id="button2" value="Button2"></input>
<input type="button" id="button3" value="Button3"></input>

<div id="content-of-button">

</div>
```

jquery: if you do not know how to put jquery code in your page use , and put your jquery or javascript code inside of this tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var button1content='Button 1 content';
   var button2content='Button 2 content';
   var button3content='Button 3 content';

   $('#button1').click(function(){
      $('#content-of-button').html(button1content);  //here .html overwrites the text inside of the target div          
      //you can also use .append() but it will add the text, not overwrite
   });

   $('#button2').click(function(){
      $('#content-of-button').html(button2content);
   });

   $('#button3').click(function(){
      $('#content-of-button').html(button3content);
   });
});
```

Don't forget to import jquery library in your head tag. Also here is the code that you can test: http://jsfiddle.net/4BpLg/6/